# nuxt, ...mapState value is returned as undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I fetch an api in my page's `fetch()` hook and then through an action and a mutation I update a value in my state called `movieList`. I know actions and mutations work because I can see them logging the response object correctly. But my page doesn't seem to find `movieList` in my store so it returns undefined. This is my folder structure:

[image]

This is my state:

```
const state = () => ({
  movieList: 'pashmi'
});
```

pelase note I initialized `movieList: 'pashmi'` to test to see if `...mapState` returns `pashmi` or not but it still returns undefined. This is my mapState:

```
import { mapState } from "vuex";
  computed: {
    ...mapState("movies", ["movieList"]),
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename movies.js to index.js, should work.